# :focus pseudo selector style not being removed when a new tab is opened , even though blur event is fired

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, css-selectors

I am working on a nav menu which contains some external url links, There are focus styles associated with the navigation menu , like the menu item gets a background when it is focused. If an item, that is an anchor which points to an external link, is clicked, it opens a new tab and displays the page that is represented by that external link. My  problem is that, even though a new tab is opened when the user comes back to the original tab, he can still see the background behind the clicked nav menu item. There are no :active styles associated with that menuitem.

I created this example in js fiddle to enumerate the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/bc5yu44v/2/

```
<body>
  <a id="selectMe" href="www.google.com" target="_blank" onblur="changeText()">clcik here</a>   
</body>
```

Here you can see that even after a new tab is opened by clicking the anchor tag , the anchor tag does not loose its :focus style, but you can see that text was changed , indicating that onblur event was fired.

can any body point me on how to remove :hover style?, is this possible by only using pseudo selector or it can only be achieved by writing js and toggling the classes?. I have a restriction of not using jquery too. I have tested it in chrome and firefox only.

Comment: I think that it's the default behavior of browsers. But you can easyly fix this with `title.blur();` [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/bc5yu44v/3/).

Answer (score 1):

This happens because navigating away from a page causes the *page* to lose focus, which takes the focus away from any element within the page that may have been in focus at the time, which is why the element's blur event is fired.

Once you navigate back to the page (or in this case the tab/window containing the page), focus is returned to the element that was in focus at the time, and if you had an onfocus event handler on the element, that would fire as well. The element does not lose its focus permanently between page or window focus/blur events. Similar behavior can be observed simply by switching windows, switching tabs, or opening and closing Start if you're on Windows.

You can force the element to lose its own focus by explicitly calling `.blur()` at the end of the event handler, but I would not do this with an onblur event handler but an onclick event handler instead, because otherwise the element would defocus itself when you switch tabs, etc.